# How to use JSON value in input log as event key in Filebeat kafka output?

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat

The Elastic documentation states that the [event key can be extracted from the event using a format string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/kafka-output.html#_key_2) But unfortunately, I couldn't find any proper example for it.

My input file contains a json object which also has nested json objects:

```
{"attribute":"XYZ","operation":"ABC","params":{"id":"12345"},"serviceId":"service_1","deployedRegion":"US"},"timestamp":1659420866000,""stats":{"type”:FILEBEAT,”retry":"0"}}
```

I want the filebeat kafka output event to get the key dynamically from the kafka event. From the above sample json provided, i want the kafka event key to be the value of "id".

I have tried multiple combinations of the output.kafka.key value but unsuccessful so far. Here is my kafka output configuration:

```
output.kafka:
  hosts: ["localhost:9092"]
  topic: 'TEST'
  required_acks: 1
  version: '0.11.0.2'
  compression: none
  max_retries: 3
  broker_timeout: 15
  codec.format:
    string: '%{[message]}'
  key: '%{[message.id]:default}'
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - drop_fields:
      fields: ["@metadata","ecs", "log","input","host","agent"]
      ignore_missing: false
```

Any support is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `message.params.id`?

Comment: Please update the question to include the associated input configuration and any processors you have applied. In order to provide an answer one would need to know if the NDJSON input file lines have been parsed.

Comment: @AJ added the processors that I am using too

Comment: The question still does not show any input configuration (e.g. filebeat.inputs).